# Minimising an objective function which is a method of a class

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, class-method

I have a class `XYZ()` with methods `build` and `Predict`. I have another class `BuildSurrogate()` which has an attribute `SurrogateClass` pointing to an object of type class `XYZ()`. A method of `SurrogateClass` is `_minima` which is defined below.

```
class XYZ():
        ...

    def build(self):
        ...

    def Predict(self):
        ...

class BuildSurrogate():
    def __init__(self, args):
        self.SurrogateClass = XYZ(*args)

    def _minima(self):
        """
        This returns the minima of the surrogate
        """

        x0 = copy(self.x0_)
        solution = minimize(fun=self.SurrogateClass.Predict, x0=x0, args=args, method='Nelder-Mead')# x0=x0, options={'xtol':1e-5,'ftol':1e-5})
        return solution
```

The script raises an error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/optiblade/Optimizer/SurrogateModel.py", line 1067, in <module>
    print SurrogateObj._minima()
  File "/path/to/optiblade/Optimizer/SurrogateModel.py", line 1006, in _minima
    solution = minimize(fun=self.SurrogateClass.Predict, x0=x0, method='Nelder-Mead')# x0=x0, options={'xtol':1e-5,'ftol':1e-5})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py", line 435, in minimize
    return _minimize_neldermead(fun, x0, args, callback, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 439, in _minimize_neldermead
    fsim[0] = func(x0)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I presume this error is raised because `self` where `self = self.SurrogateClass` is to be passed to `Predict`. Do I have to change my code structure or is there a way I can solve the above problem without changing my code structure?

Comment: what version of scipy? also, are you showing all arguments to XYZ.Predict, or have you elided some of them?

Comment: Better show the actual code you're using, thus including the full code for `Predict`.

Comment: `Setting an array element with a sequence` would suggest that `func(x0)` returned a sequence, so I'm assuming that your `Predict` method accidentally returned a sequence when it shouldn't.

Comment: Pedantry: it's not Pythonic to have CamelCase names for method, function, variable and attribute names: those tend to be used only for class names (*not* instances). I'm mentioning it, because `self.SurrogateClass.Predict` read as classes, not an instance and method.

Comment: You're using Python 2: better inherit from `object`, instead of inheriting from nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with an example for `minimize` documentation:

```
In [183]: x0 = [1.3, 0.7, 0.8, 1.9, 1.2]
In [185]: optimize.minimize(optimize.rosen, x0, method='Nelder-Mead', tol=1e-6)
Out[185]: 
 final_simplex: (array([[ 1.00000002,  1.00000002,  1.00000007,  1.00000015,  1.00000028],
...
             x: array([ 1.00000002,  1.00000002,  1.00000007,  1.00000015,  1.00000028])
```

Define a callable class that does the same thing:

```
In [191]: class Class1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def __call__(self,args):
        return optimize.rosen(args)
In [190]: optimize.minimize(Class1(), x0, method='Nelder-Mead', tol=1e-6)
```

A `Class1` object is callable, so I can use it exactly as though I had defined a `rosen` method

```
In [191]: Class1()(x0)
Out[191]: 848.22000000000003
```

I could have defined it this way:

```
In [192]: class Class2(object):
    def rosen(self,args):
        return optimize.rosen(args)   

In [193]: optimize.minimize(Class2().rosen, x0, method='Nelder-Mead', tol=1e-6)

In [194]: Class2().rosen(x0)
Out[194]: 848.22000000000003
```

Adding in class layer shouldn't make a difference, just so long as the first argument to `minimize` is a function that returns a value when called with `x0`.

In your case you just need to define:

```
class XYZ(object):
    def predict(self, args):
        return optimize.rosen(args)

class BuildSurrogate(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.surrogateObj = XYZ()
    def minima(self,x0):
        return optimize.minimize(self.surrogateObj.predict, x0, method='Nelder-Mead', tol=1e-6)
```

And use:

```
BuildSurrogate().minima(x0)
```

Or something comparable.

I could have also defined `self.SurrogateClass=XYZ` and called `self.SurrogateClass().predict`.  As long as `predict` is a method of the `XYZ` class I have to create an `XYZ()` object before using it.